# Angular 2 - /traceur 404

Tags: angular

I'm moving from rc4 of Angular to version 2 directly.

However I have this error:

[image: Error 404 traceur]

I searched a bit and it is not commented at the beginning of files that cause this error. Do you have ideas of the origin of this problem?

Comment: You should check your `system.config,js` https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/2.0.0/systemjs.config.js

Comment: I'm use function for build this config, and the result is similary

Comment: Which version of systemjs do you use? What is your transpiler set to in the config?

Comment: RC4, but i'm modified this config

Comment: It's good for this error, but, now it's my appComponent who doesn't work and i've not error log

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at some point, and I think it was related to minification and/or mangling. Are you using systemjs-builder to create a bundle? If so, try to disable these, and/or update systemjs-builder to the latest version to see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just then. Try clearing the browser cache and disabling it during developer mode